# How to remove parent fields in json variable and convert it to json in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am working on some project which has lot of objects involvement. I have below requirement in javascript or jQuery.

I have below object:

```
var dataset = {
    "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
    "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
    "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
};
```

How can I remove parent fields and make it as object like below ?

```
var d= [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
]
```

After doing this, I wanted to pass this object to a javascript function which manipulates the value of this variable d.

```
if(value >= 10 && value <= 20) {
    d[index].value = 7;
}
if(value >= 20 && value <= 40) {
    d[index].value = 8;
}
```

Updated object should look like :

```
var d= [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 7 },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 8 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
]
```

I tried looping to the dataset using for loop, but couldn't achieve my requirement.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over object.

```js
var dataset = {
    "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
    "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
    "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
};

// Declare resulting empty array
var d = [];

// Get object keys and iterate over them
Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function (key) {
    // Get the value from the object
    var value = dataset[key].value;

    // Update values if in the range
    if(value >= 10 && value <= 20) {
        dataset[key].value = 7;
    } else if(value > 20 && value <= 40) {
        dataset[key].value = 8;
    }

    // Push the updated(or not) value in the array
    d.push(dataset[key]);
});

console.log(d);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Am just curious, how can I do the exact reverse of this ? like, converting d variable to original dataset containing d0,d1,... ?

Comment: @SathishPanduga Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hx6tyjvp/). **Code** `var dataset = {};
d.forEach(function (e, i) {
    dataset['d' + i] = e;
});`. The values that are transformed by the `if` conditions is lost, cannot be get back.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much Tushar :)

Comment: Hi Tushar, Could you please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478943/difficulty-adding-object-as-innerhtml-to-a-dynamically-created-div-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Just map it with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var dataset = {
    "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
    "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
    "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
};

var d = Object.keys(dataset).map(function(key) {
    var obj = dataset[key];
    if (obj.value >= 10 && obj.value <= 20) {
        obj.value = 7;
    }
    else if (obj.value >= 20 && obj.value <= 40) {
        obj.value = 8;
    }
    return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(d, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: plus one for the use of 2nd and (mainly) 3rd parameters of `stringify` ... minus one for the use of `document.write` :p

Comment: nothing for demo/snippet purposes - other than that, it's an abomination :p

Comment: `document.write` is the best `console.log` alternative for SO snippets, does its job perfectly. There was `alert` but it's not longer possible to use it unfortunately. But other that demo, of course `document.write` is not the coolest thing.

Comment: No need of using `=` in `obj.value >= 20` in `else if` condition since `20` is already covered in `if`.

Comment: Hi, Could you please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478943/difficulty-adding-object-as-innerhtml-to-a-dynamically-created-div-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var dataset = {
        "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
        "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
        "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
        "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
        "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
    };
```

First remove the string keys:

```
var d = [];
for(var k in dataset){
    d.push(dataset[k]);
}
```

Then iterate over resulting array modifying it accordingly:

```
for(var k in d){
    var value = d[k]['value'];
    if(value>=10 && value<=20){
        d[k].value=7;
    }
    if(value>=20 && value<=40){
        d[k].value=8;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `for-in` loop ever for arrays.

Comment: **1.** There's no need of iterating over object **twice**. You can combine/merge those two `for` loops to increase performance. **2.** `for...in` is _slow_

Comment: @Tushar I know, but that was OP's requirement  - first make array of values.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the resuls you're looking for:

```
var dataset = {
    "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 },
    "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
    "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
    "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
    "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
};

var d = Object.keys(dataset).map(function(key) {
    var v = dataset[key].value;
    if (v >= 10 && v <= 20) dataset[key].value = 7;
    else if (v > 20 && v <= 40) dataset[key].value = 8;
    return dataset[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function datasetToArrOfObj(dataset){

    var rslt = [];

    for (var key in dataset) {
      if (dataset.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         rslt.push(dataset[key]);
      }
    }
return rslt;    
}
```